# How to remove repeating symbol from character variable in R?

Tags: character, measure

In my dataframe I have height in inches, which is writing this way:
[height in inches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLCTa.png)

How to delete the sybol of inches (") from the whole column?

I have tried noquote function.
Also I have tried to do it in this way:

```
trauma$Height = str_replace_all(trauma$Height, "[[:punct:]]", " ")
trauma$Height = chartr(' ',',', trauma$Height)
```

but at the end I had variable like 68,8,